# vb.net save listbox items empty lines

Tags: vb.net, listbox, savefiledialog

I want to save listbox items to a txt file while using savefiledialog

This is the code I'm using, it's working but it will put a new line between every item. And I'd like to save without those empty lines. If anyone could help, thanks!

My code:

```
            If ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then
        SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:/"
        SaveFileDialog1.Title = "YOUR RESULTS"
        SaveFileDialog1.FileName = Label4.Text
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = ("text files (*.txt) | *.txt")

        SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

        Dim w As New IO.StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            w.WriteLine(ListBox1.Items(i).ToString)
        Next
        w.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("There is nothing to save", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove spaces from the start of a string, use the default [`String.TrimStart()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method, as follows:

```
w.WriteLine(ListBox1.Items(i).ToString.TrimStart)
```

To remove only spaces from the end, use the default `String.TrimEnd()`
extension method, and for remove both spaces from start and end of a string, use `String.Trim()`

### Update

I suggest you to use a `StringBuilder` object as follows:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder

For Each lbItem As Object In ListBox1.Items
    sb.Append(lbItem.ToString)
Next

File.WriteAllText(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, sb.ToString, Encoding.Default)
```

Comment: Tried it, but still getting spaces.

Comment: You really mean a space, or a NEW LINE?.